# Как вычислить цену без скидки и округлить?

Tags: php

Есть 2 переменные: цена со скидкой и размер скидки. Нужно вывести изначальную цену без скидки. Делаю это так:

```
$discount = 53;
$price = 1000;
echo floor(($price/(100-$discount)*100)/10)*10 // выведет 2120;
```

Как сделать округление в большую сторону до 50 (например, в примере вместо 2120 должно получиться 2150), или до сотен, если десятков больше пяти (2160 -> 2200)?

Answer (score 1):

Могли бы хотя бы попытаться решить задачу самостоятельно

```
function myRound($value) {
    $remain = $value % 100;

    if ($remain === 0) {
        return $value;
    } elseif ($remain <= 50) {
        return $value + (50 - $remain);
    }

    return $value + (100 - $remain);
}

$array = array_fill_keys([2100, 2120, 2150, 2170], null);

foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $array[$key] = myRound($key);
}

print_r($array);
```

> Array (
>       [2100] => 2100
>       [2120] => 2150
>       [2150] => 2150
>       [2170] => 2200 )

Comment: а если 2 ключа одинаковых?

Comment: @Bloom, код ниже функции является демонстрацией её работы. Не более. Юнит-тест так сказать